# Как расположить медиафайлы в произвольных папках на wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Возможно ли расположить медиафайлы не по месяцам и году, а произвольно - аватарки, миниатюры к записям, к примеру так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого есть разные плагины, например [WordPress Media Library Folders](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-plus/).